# Is HashSet of a HashSet<T> the right data model here?

Tags: c#

I'm managing a data structure that looks like the following

```json
[
    {
        "name": "Yada yada",
        "dataModels": [
            {
                "entity": "Table",
                "columns": [
                    [
                        {
                            "column": "ColumnA",
                            "value": " \"StringA\""
                        },
                        {
                            "column": "ColumnB",
                            "value": " \"StringB\""
                        }
                    ],
                    ...,
                    [
                        {
                            "column": "ColumnA",
                            "value": " \"StringA\""
                        },
                        {
                            "column": "ColumnB",
                            "value": " \"StringB\""
                        }
                    ],
                    ...
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Every object in the `columns` list is a `HashSet` of `ColumnValues`, a class I created and is defined the following way:

```
public class ColumnValues
    {
        private string column;
        private string value;

        public ColumnValues(string col, string val)
        {
            column = col;
            value = val;
        }

        public string Column
        {
            get {return column;}
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get {return value;}
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is ColumnValues values &&
                   column == values.column &&
                   value == values.value &&
                   Column == values.Column &&
                   Value == values.Value;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(column, value, Column, Value);
        }
    }
```

So far, so good. However the issue is that in `columns`, I'm having duplicates of lists. `columns` is a field in `DataModel`, another class:

```
public class DataModel
    {
        private string entity;
        private List<HashSet<ColumnValues>> columns;
        private string rule;
        public DataModel(string entityName, List<HashSet<ColumnValues>> columnList)
        {
            entity = entityName;
            columns = columnList;
        }
        public string Entity
        {
            get { return entity; }
        }
        public List<HashSet<ColumnValues>> Columns
        {
            get { return columns; }
            set { columns = value; }
        }

        public string Rule
        {
            set { rule = value; }
        }
    }
```

I'm not understanding why the Set is allowing the existence of duplicates.

I do add that I'm returning the `columns` list after applying `Distinct().ToList()`:

```
var dataModels = new List<DataModel>();
GatherColumns(code.Syntax);
dataModels.ForEach(dataModel => dataModel.Columns = dataModel.Columns.Distinct().ToList());
return dataModels;
```

TIA!

**EDIT:**

As per Tim's comment, I've provided the override methods `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.
I've also decided to define `Columns` in `DataModel` as a List of HashSets.
However, unfortunately the result hasn't changed.

---

**EDIT N°2:**

I've decided to create a class implementing the `IEqualityComparer` interface. However, little effect so far:

```
public class ColumnValuesComparer : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<ColumnValues>>
    {
        public bool Equals(HashSet<ColumnValues> c1, HashSet<ColumnValues> c2)
        {
            return c1.Equals(c2);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(HashSet<ColumnValues> obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Used here:

```
var dataModels = new List<DataModel>();
GatherColumns(code.Syntax);
ColumnValuesComparer comparer = new ColumnValuesComparer();
dataModels.ForEach(dataModel => dataModel.Columns = dataModel.Columns.Distinct(comparer).ToList());
return dataModels;
```

At this point I'm pretty much stuck, and don't know where to go moving forward.

Comment: …how do you think HashSet works?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with C#, coming from Python. But afaik, similar implementations with a C# twist. I'm however familiar with the data structure.

Comment: If you use a custom type in a `HashSet<T>` you have to override `Equals`and `GetHashCode`. How should the set know your definition of "equal" otherwise? It will just use [`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0#definition) which compares references.

Comment: Why are you using a `HashSet` in the first place? What made you choose it? If you start learning a new language, you should start with a relative clean slate: trying to map knowledge you have from other languages can lead to misunderstandings and misconceptions.

Comment: I'm dealing in a relatively nested data structure. I'm handling couples of (unique) key/value objects, that need to be grouped within a list (set). That group of couples also needs to be unique amongst other groups of couples inside a bigger list.
I've decided to go with HashSet because I thought it had a similar implementation as in Python, but I happen to be incorrect :)

Comment: In Python a hashable object needs a fitting __hash__ and __eq__ method pretty similar actually to the need for Equals/GetHashCode in C#.

Comment: Edited code. Added the override methods as mentioned above.

Comment: Know you prevent duplicates in one HashSet. But you want now distinct HashSet(s) or do you want distinct values in all of the HashSet(s)? So a columnA in the first HashSet isn't also allowed in the second HashSet? Or are just identical columnlists not allowed. In that case does order of columns matter or not?

Comment: I don't mind the keys (names) of the columns, i'm mostly focused on their values. So I want distinct HashSets. Columns order doesn't matter to me. Like in the example I provided, I don't want to have 2 exact hashsets.

Comment: From what I see in your json structure I would expect it to be an Array<T>, List<T> or Collection<T>.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of searching a documentation, I fell upon the concept of [`SetComparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.createsetcomparer?view=net-7.0).
They allow me to create objects that evaluate deep nested equality within HashSets.

So, when I try to create my HashSet of HashSets, I must pass that method:

```
var set = new HashSet<HashSet<ColumnValues>>(HashSet<ColumnValues>.CreateSetComparer());
set.Add(columnValues);
```